# Command Prompt can't find my java files no matter what i do

Tags: java, class, find

I've been trying to get this to work practically all day. I'm fairly new to programming and I had an assignment for school to create a chat server (though this is beside the point). So I finished my program and wanted to test it but no matter what i do my class files cant be found in the command prompt for some odd reason. Ive tried everything as far as changing the path and I'm not sure whats going on. I did a quick hello world java file just to make sure it wasn't something in the actual program but I ran into the same problem. I screenshotted the error i keep getting and attached it. As you can see, the helloworld is in the right place on the desktop but for some reason it just wont find my files. Thanks for nay help you can give.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vPDC.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a method in the HelloWorld class ``public static void main(String[] args)``?

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether you have saved your file in .java format.
To check that, right click your file and click "properties" option to view your file format. I have added the screenshot of my java file. If you look into that, Type of file is "JAVA file .java"[Attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHFdm.png)

Answer (score 0):

As **Sneha Veerakumar's** answer, make sure your file is in .java extension. Not .txt or other. But if the file has been in .java and the same issue still appears, check your JAVA_HOME environtment variables, make sure this is set correctly as well.

JAVA_HOME environtment variables in Windows:

1. Go to Control Panel > System
2. Navigate to Advanced system settings
3. Choose Environment Variables.
4. Edit/Add JAVA_HOME variable with the value of the JDK path, example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
5. Add the JDK bin path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin to the value of 'Path' variable. With semicolon(;) delimiter.